# Why does my filterInput receive a formatted number containing punctuation in certain cases?

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I have a text field that I want to limit to integers only. See the code below.

When the view containing the field starts, and if the model is constructed with an initial default value for `someInteger`, the view displays the number correctly, without extra formatting. It also filters new typed input as expected.

A problem arises when refactoring the model not to have a default value. Being an integer property, it defaults to 0. When I later assign a new value to the property, the `controlNewText` passed contains punctuation, such as `1,234`. That causes the check to fail and the newly assigned value to be filtered out of the view.

Why is the `controlNewText` getting formatted in the first place? Is there a way to prevent that?

```
textfield(model.someInteger) {
    required()
    textFormatter = TextFormatter(IntegerStringConverter(), model.item.someInteger)
    stripNonInteger()
    filterInput { it.controlNewText.isInt() }
}

class SomeData {
    val someIntegerProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "someInteger")
    var someInteger by someIntegerProperty
}

class SomeDataModel : ItemViewModel<SomeData>(SomeData()) {
    val someInteger = bind(SomeData::someIntegerProperty)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting is performed by the `TextFormatter` you specified. Make sure to specify one that doesn't add thousand separators. Here is a complete runnable application that configures a `NumberStringConverter` inside the formatter. Notice that I've removed the `filterInput` statement, as that's already covered by `stripNonInteger`.

```
class MainView : View("Main view") {
    val model = SomeDataModel()

    override val root = borderpane {
        center {
            form {
                fieldset {
                    field("Some integer") {
                        textfield(model.someInteger) {
                            required()
                            textFormatter = TextFormatter(NumberStringConverter("########"), model.someInteger.value)
                            stripNonInteger()
                        }
                    }
                    button("Set some value").action {
                        model.someInteger.value = 1234
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeData {
    val someIntegerProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "someInteger")
    var someInteger by someIntegerProperty
}

class SomeDataModel : ItemViewModel<SomeData>(SomeData()) {
    val someInteger = bind(SomeData::someIntegerProperty)
}
```